# "Update" instead of "save" in Django model without the primary key

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

How to do an "Update" instead of "save". I want to make a new entry only if "name", "age" already does not exists. I cannot handle/pass the primary key.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    goes_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    flag = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    objects = models.Manager()



def saveauthor(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        nname = request.POST['name']
        nage = request.POST['age']
        nalias = request.POST['alias']
        ngoes_by = request.POST['goes_by']
        nflag = request.POST['flag']
        new = Author(name = nname, age = nage, alias = nalias, goes_by= ngoes_by, flag=nflag)
        new.save()    
     else:
        pass
    return JsonResponse("Ok", safe=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
from django.db.models import Q
def saveauthor(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if Author.objects.filter(Q(name=request.POST["name"])|Q(age=request.POST["age"])).first():
           return JsonResponse(?)
        nname = request.POST['name']
        nage = request.POST['age']
        nalias = request.POST['alias']
        ngoes_by = request.POST['goes_by']
        nflag = request.POST['flag']
        new = Author(name = nname, age = nage, alias = nalias, goes_by= ngoes_by, flag=nflag)
        new.save()    
     else:
        pass
    return JsonResponse("Ok", safe=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `update_or_create` method:

```
defaults = { "alias": nalias, "goes_by": ngoes_by, "flag": nflag }
Author.objects.update_or_create(name = nname, age = nage, defaults = defaults)
```

See here for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Answer (score 2):

You can work with [**`.update_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create):

```
Author.objects.update_or_create(
    name=nname,
    age = nage,
    defaults=dict(alias=nalias, goes_by=ngoes_by, flag=nflag)
)
```

Comment: But remember that "As described above in get_or_create(), this method is prone to a race-condition which can result in multiple rows being inserted simultaneously if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level."

Comment: Just discovered this race condition, this is actually making multiple entries.

Comment: @KapishM: yes, as said, you should make the combination of `name` and `age` unique with a [**`UniqueConstraint`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint).